# Before/After is not working in catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml inside sidebar.main?

Tags: magento2, layout, layered-navigation, sorting

I am trying to add a string at the top of the product details page navigation `referenceContainer name="sidebar.main"` but the string is coming after product Filters.

How can i change or move my block at the top of the filters section or sidebar main, as i have tried so many ways but no luck as i added below.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
          <block class="I95dev\Categorysearch\Block\Index\Index" name="index_index" template="index/index.phtml" before="-">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the layered nav is also set to `before="-"`, the fix is to move the layered nav so it displays after your new block.

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="index_index" />
```

---

---

---

#### Old Answer

<s>It's likely happening because the product filters also have `before="-"` set, so both are fighting to display first. I think setting your block to display before the product filters (name is `catalog.leftnav`) will fix it, like so:</s>

```
<block class="I95dev\Categorysearch\Block\Index\Index" name="index_index" template="index/index.phtml" before="catalog.leftnav" />
```

~~Or~~

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="index_index" />
```

---

~~I'm not sure if this matters but I usually prefix the template with the module so the template would be:~~

```
template="I95dev/Categorysearch::index/index.phtml"
```

Comment: I have tried this also, but not working

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev Hmmm possibly try it the other way round then, so move `catalog.leftnav` to be after your block? Off the top of my head it would be along the lines of `<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="index_index" />`

Comment: Ok, I am posting the comment by my mobile, I will try and update you on my system. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, if it works I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ Ben Crook, Move element is working as expected, layouts are always confusing. :) Thanks.